# How do programs approximate polynomials with degrees greater than one?

Tags: linear-algebra

I just learned best approximation and least squares in my linear algebra course and I was wondering how programs approximate solutions with a degree greater than one? Would it still be possible with the approximation of least squares? Or do they use a different algorithm?

Comment: Look at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPolynomial.html).

Comment: Least-squares can be easily generalised to any hypothesis of the form $y=\sum_i a_i f_i (x)+\epsilon$; see as an exercise is you can reduce the calculus to a problem of matrix inversion.

Comment: Any numerical analysis text will have a section proving what J.G. has said.

Comment: To be pedantic: _least squares_ is a criteria, not an algorithm. There exist several algorithms to get the optimum solution according to this critera

Comment: To be even more pedantic, the singular noun is *criterion*.

Comment: Do you mean "approximate roots to a polynomial of degree greater than $1$" (in which case the solution is things like Newton's method), or "find the best polynomial with degree greater than one to approximate a sequence of data points"? Those are very different questions!

Comment: @YiFan The second one, but I think my question has been sufficiently answered.